# Parameters to store

Tags: extjs, pagination, store, param

i have a students json data store of a school. The students are enrolled in courses.
And i need, show students by course. So i have the next paginated store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Alumnos', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.Alumno',
    autoLoad: false,
    start: 0,
    pageSize: 20,
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'mvc/stores/Alumnos.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```

And i like, not have a store for each course. Then, when i load the store, send by param the idCourse:

```
/**
 * Muestra la ventana de gestion de un grado.
 * @param {int} id course.
 * @return {void}
 */
mostrarAbmAlumnos: function(idGradoSolicitado) {
    var store = Ext.create('AM.store.Alumnos', {}).load({
        params: {idGrado: idGradoSolicitado}
    });
}
```

For the first page, the store works fine, but when i click "next page", the idCourse not trip to server.

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When i create the data store, before load it, bind the extraParams at the Proxy.
According the doc:

> extraParams : Object Extra parameters that will be included on every
>   request. Individual requests with params of the same name will
>   override these params when they are in conflict.

Note: I use ExtJs 4, in previous version, extraParams are called baseParams.

So, the correct code would:

```
var store = Ext.create('AM.store.Alumnos', {});
store.getProxy().extraParams.idGrado = idGradoSolicitado;
store.load();
```

And work fine !.